How to extract table data from an image in iOS and retain the tabular format?
I am working on an iOS application where I need to extract table data from an image uploaded by the user. The goal is to retain the exact tabular format so that the data can be printed or displayed as a table.
Here’s what I have tried so far:
Apple Vision Framework: I used the VNRecognizeTextRequest for text recognition. While it successfully extracts text, the output is not structured and lacks the original tabular format, making it difficult to reconstruct the table.
TesseractOCR: I tried setting up TesseractOCR for this purpose, but I ran into multiple setup issues and was unable to get it working.
I am looking for a reliable solution to extract table data from an image and retain its tabular format. The extracted data should ideally be structured so that it can be directly used to render a table.
My Doubts are ->

Are there any libraries or techniques (preferably for iOS) that can help extract table data while preserving the tabular format?
If TesseractOCR is a good option, is there a reliable way to set it up for an iOS project?
Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

